# module "bb.data" is not installed

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry 10 .I just Run the sample code given in documentation but it is giving me error that {  module "bb.data" is not installed  }

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.data 1.0

Page {
    content: ListView {
        id: listView
        dataModel: dataModel
        //...
    }
    attachedObjects: [
        GroupDataModel {
            id: dataModel
        },
        DataSource {
            id: dataSource
            source: "contacts.json"
            onDataLoaded: {
                dataModel.insertList(data)
            }
        }
    ]

    onCreationCompleted: {
        dataSource.load();

    }
}
```

Then According to documentation i add a flag in .pro file

```
LIBS += -lbbdata
```

and i also upgrade the SDK but no luck if any one know please help me and

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does that error occur in QML Preview window or on an app running? Is building process completing successfully?

Comment: This is error in my preview window . it build and run successfully. but also there is another problem   [


{ "id":1, "firstname": "Mike", "lastname": "Chepesky", "title": "Sr. Editor",
   "active": true, "gender": "m" },


{ "id":2, "firstname": "Westlee", "lastname": "Barichak", "title": "Talent Scout",
   "active": false, "gender": "m" }
  
  
] This is the data in my JSON but my list only show the false and true how can i specify what to show or what to not.

Comment: Please create a separate question regarding ListView and JSON problem with code specified. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before 10.2 SDK version QML Preview could load and render components based on the Cascades plug-in only (in bb.cascades 1.0).

Since 10.2 the rendering capabilities of QML Preview have been extended to provide rendering of more custom controls, however not sure about which libraries and components are supported at the moment.

Please, have a look here for more information on this:

- [10.1 Limitations](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/releasenotes/#limitations)
- [New in 10.2 Beta Release](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/releasenotes_beta_10_2/#new)

Comment: This needs Upgrading the System but sir if you know any other way to install modules in QNX momentics  because i see in the given link they require some other changing also.

Comment: You don't need to install native BB10 modules. They are coming with the SDK. QML Preview rendering and modules functionality is independent thing.

Comment: But i am not able to understand how to solve this error whereas i am  using latest stable version of SDK.

Comment: There is no way to 'solve' the error except by installing version 10.2 of Momentics where the QML previewer has been updated to allow the inclusion of modules other than `bb.cascades`. https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/beta/